# Storing a generic Action in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, func

`T` is fine for the method but doesn't work for the `Dictionary` without defining `T` on the class which I can't do. Is this possible? If not, is there another way to accomplish storing generic callback methods like this.

This class is for a Websockets Json-Rpc client. The API I'm connecting to allows you to subscribe to different data streams. I.e. stock quotes, stock trades, etc which all have different fields.

I'd like to be able to pass in the name of the data to subscribe to, then a callback, and it's param type, which will pass in the data once it's returned.

```
// Store list of callback to invoke once data arrives
private Dictionary<string, Action<T>> _callbacks = new Dictionary<string, Action<T>>();

// Subscribe to websocket API streaming data
public async Task SubscribeAsync<T>(string name, Action<T> callback)
{
    _callbacks.Add(name, callback);

    ... other code here ...

}

// Data is eventually received here from the websocket API
private async Task _wsClient_OnDataReceived(string jsonData)
{
    var docRoot = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonData).RootElement;
    var deserialzizedData = ...
    _callbacks[dataName].Invoke(deserialzizedData);
}
```

Comment: If you define your dictionary as a member of the class, then yes, your class needs to provide the generic argument. Can you give more details about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @gunr2171 added more details to the OP

Comment: @user3953989 Can you show the code where you are adding items to the dictionary?

Comment: How would you call the callback anyway if you don't know its parameter type? Perhaps `_wsClient_OnDataReceived` would need to be generic also, then you can use simple type-casting after looking up the callback in the dictionary

Comment: @Charlieface Inside the `_wsClient_OnDataReceived` event I have to parse the Json to determine which type it is, then manually deserialize to that type. The idea being the caller of the `Subscribe<T>` method should know which type goes with what data they're subscribing to, then in code I can invoke the callback Func with whatever type they passed used.

Comment: @MikeHofer It's the first line in the `SubscribeAsync` method.

Comment: So make `_wsClient_OnDataReceived` generic also, and use the answer below from @dbCoder then the calling code would know which type it is and you can feed that through to the type parameter of `SubMgr`

Comment: @Charlieface Then I would have to create a new client for every type passed into the callback would I not? Can you also give an example of making `_wsClient_OnDataReceived` generic as well?

Comment: Declare a generic `_wsClient_OnDataReceived <T>` the within that retrieve the callback from `SubMgr<T>._callbacks`. You should modify it so that `_callbacks` is `static`

Comment: @user3953989 It sounds like you want to be able to store multiple types in the `Dictionary`. That is, for `Action<T>`, `T` may change for each item. Is that a true statement?

Comment: @MikeHofer Yes, correct. The server may send different types and they all get captured in that receive method and converted from Json to a type and passed into the Action<T> stored in the Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to store multiple potentially polymorphic types in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. However, the dictionary expects that every item in it will have exactly the same type. So, in your case, every `Action<T>` must be exactly the same, meaning that `<T>` must be the same type for all instances.

You can get around this, however, if  is an interface. For example:

```
private Dictionary<string, Action<IActionable>> _callbacks = new Dictionary<string, Action<IActionable>>();
```

where `IActionable` is some common interface that all the types implement. Or, instead of an interface, it's a common base class that they all inherit from.

In any event, the point is that you want `Action<T>` to be the same, but treat the instances polymorphically. To do so, you need either an interface that they implement or a common base class with the method you want to invoke. You'll add items to the dictionary as instances of either the interface or base class, and you'll invoke the desired method through the same.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Note that `SubscribeAsync<T> became SubscribeAsync` as type is passed in 2nd parameter:

```
namespace Callbacks {
    class SubMgr<T> {
        private Dictionary<string, Action<T>> _callbacks = new Dictionary<string, Action<T>>();

        public async Task SubscribeAsync(string name, Action<T> callback ) {

            _callbacks.Add(name, callback);
            _callbacks.Add(name, Method1);
            _callbacks.Add(name, Method2);

            // ... other code here...
        }

        public void Method1(T a) { }
        public void Method2(T a) { }

    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this my ApiClient will be tied to only receiving one type that's defined when the class is instantiated. I need to be able to receive different types as the server sends them.

Comment: See answer by @Mike Hofer for clarifications